# Terraform: Providing list of yaml command inside variables.tf

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a `script.yml` with many commands that I would like to pass on to my terraform-aws-imagebuilder-component-shell module. This yaml file is needed to harden my ec2-image-builder pipeline. I can easily create this component of the pipeline from the aws console image builder but I am trying to terraform the whole project that I got from here --> https://github.com/rhythmictech/terraform-aws-imagebuilder-component-shell. I am new to Terraform and based on my research I need to inject my list of commands from my yaml file in my `variables.tf`. See my codes below:

`script.yml` (the file is longer than this but just to give you an idea)

```
schemaVersion: 1.0

phases:
  - name: build
    steps:
      - name: CISBenchmarkHardening
        action: ExecuteBash
        inputs:
          commands:

            # §1.1
            - echo "install cramfs /bin/true" > /etc/modprobe.d/cramfs.conf
            - echo "install vfat /bin/true" > /etc/modprobe.d/vfat.conf
            - echo "install squashfs /bin/true" > /etc/modprobe.d/squashfs.conf
            - echo "install udf /bin/true" > /etc/modprobe.d/udf.conf
            - echo "install usb-storage /bin/true" > /etc/modprobe.d/usb-storage.conf

            # §1.2
            - echo "localpkg_gpgcheck=1" >> /etc/yum.conf
```

`variables.tf`

```
variable "change_description" {
  default     = null
  description = "description of changes since last version"
  type        = string
}

variable "cloudformation_timeout" {
  default     = 10
  description = "How long to wait (in minutes) for CFN to apply before giving up"
  type        = number
}

variable "commands" {
  default     = ["command 1"] # need to update
  description = "List of strings. Each string is a shell command"
  type        = list(string)
}

variable "component_version" {
  default     = "1.0.0" 
  description = "Version of the component"
  type        = string
}

variable "create" {
  default     = true
  description = "A flag to disable creation of the component"
  type        = bool
}

variable "data_uri" {
  default     = null
  description = "Use this to override the component document with one at a particular URL endpoint"
  type        = string
}

variable "description" {
  default     = null
  description = "description of component"
  type        = string
}

variable "kms_key_id" {
  default     = null
  description = "KMS key to use for encryption"
  type        = string
}

variable "name" {
  default     = "testcomponent"
  description = "name to use for component"
  type        = string
}

variable "phase" {
  default     = "build"
  description = "The Image Builder phase this component is in, either 'build' or 'test'."
  type        = string
}

# TODO: add validation
variable "platform" {
  default     = "Linux"
  description = "platform of component (Linux or Windows)"
  type        = string
}

variable "tags" {
  default     = {}
  description = "map of tags to use for CFN stack and component"
  type        = map(string)
}
```

As you can see my `script.yml` file as many commands and I am wondering the smartest way to pass on those commands to my `variables.tf` or preferably keep things cleaner by having my `script.yml` seating somewhere in my repo and passing it as an input for `command` in my `variables.tf` . Hope that makes sense :( !! Let me know if I am missing something and I would greatly appreciate any pointers..Blessings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to re-use that module as is, you should follow their usage example:

```
module "test_shell_component" {
...
  commands          = ["echo 'Testing Component'"]
  tags              = local.tags
...
}
```

If you look at how they have defined their var.commands, you'll see that the requirement is `list(string)`, with a very nice description saying each string is a command:

```
variable "commands" {
  description = "List of strings. Each string is a shell command"
  type        = list(string)
}
```

Or in your case, it will be something like:

```
module "karl_test" {
  source  = "rhythmictech/imagebuilder-component-shell/aws"
  version = "~> 0.1.0"

  component_version = "1.0.0"
  description       = "Testing component"
  name              = "testing-component"
  commands          = [
        "echo "install cramfs /bin/true" > /etc/modprobe.d/cramfs.conf",
        "echo "install vfat /bin/true" > /etc/modprobe.d/vfat.conf",
        "echo "install squashfs /bin/true" > /etc/modprobe.d/squashfs.conf",
        "echo "install udf /bin/true" > /etc/modprobe.d/udf.conf",
        "echo "install usb-storage /bin/true" > /etc/modprobe.d/usb-storage.conf"
]
  tags              = local.tags
}
```